# Invalid OAuth Request in Right Signature

Tags: php, oauth

I need to integrate my website with right signature for signing documents.But I couldn't figured it out because its continously showing me Invalid OAuth Request.
I'm running this api by using php library but its keep on showing Invalid OAuth Request.I'm fed up from all this. Run on Browser below url

https://RightSignature.com/api/documents.xml

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to access a file that needs you to have api accesses. If you haven't signed up with them, then you don't have access. If you just want to see the docs, [here](https://rightsignature.com/apidocs/api_documentation_default) they are.

EDIT: btw, you need to request an API Key per their docs, and you can't even view their docs until you've signed up for an account. Once you do that, they will personally approve or deny you access to keys. With that, you have about one month to do something with it.

Comment: $headers = "";
 $secure_token="tyLSikhWBKrT0a2nyEL8CVhbvmMgsm1NGXZaa1VI";
    $url = 'http://rightsignature.com/api/documents.xml';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // Append 'api-token' to Headers
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers,"Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8", "api-token: $secure_token")); // Set the headers.
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
print_r($result);

Answer (score 0):

If you have secure token use this code:
For Json response:
Method defines GET or POST,
headers contains header part,
url is rightsignature endpoints,
secure token got after registration,
Body contains parameters.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // Append 'api-token' to Headers
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers, "api-token: $secure_token")); // Set the headers.
    // If you want parameters to be sent 
    if ($body) {
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            // Append 'api-token' to Headers
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers, "Content-Type: application/javascript;charset=utf-8", "api-token: $secure_token"));   
    }
```

For XML response:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // Append 'api-token' to Headers
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers, "api-token: $secure_token")); // Set the headers.
    // If you want parameters to be sent 
    if ($body) {
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            // Append 'api-token' to Headers
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers, "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8", "api-token: $secure_token"));   
        }
```

Comment: Hi u there wisdom?

I need to know  that what should i write in $body and $headers?? because i have to get  documents from right signature account by using api url..not POST...

Comment: $headers = "";
 $secure_token="tyLSikhWBKrT0a2nyEL8CVhbvmMgsm1NGXZaa1VI";
    $url = 'http://rightsignature.com/api/documents.xml';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // Append 'api-token' to Headers
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers,"Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8", "api-token: $secure_token")); // Set the headers.
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
print_r($result);

Comment: https://eval.in/414478    follow the link which contains class and object creation example